# Trying to iterate an associated model, CollectionProxy always has a nil entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My main model, Activity, has proper data.

```
>> @activity
=> #<Activity id: 4, name: "Take a nap", description: "Let your kids sleep when they're tired", location: "home", duration_minutes: 60, created_at: "2014-01-01 20:32:56", updated_at: "2014-01-01 20:32:56">
```

The associated model, Reviews, returns a CollectionProxy that is essentially nil. Thus causing me issues, when trying to iterate `@activity.reviews.each`, since it always has a nil CollectionProxy that it will iterate into.

```
>> @activity.reviews
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Review id: nil, rating: nil, reviewer_name: nil, activity_id: 4, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]>
>> @activity.reviews.any?
=> true
>> @activity.reviews.count
=> 0
```

If I then put some data in there, I get the real one I added, but I also still get this nil collection proxy joker.

```
>> @reviews
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Review id: 5, rating: 5, reviewer_name: "Peter", activity_id: 4, description: "I can be productive when the kids are sleeping.", created_at: "2014-01-05 03:53:08", updated_at: "2014-01-05 03:53:08">, #<Review id: nil, rating: nil, reviewer_name: nil, activity_id: 4, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]>
>> @reviews.any?
=> true
>> @reviews.count
=> 1
```

So, my question is, what do I have wrong with my associations, that I keep getting this useless nil CollectionProxy entry?

Also, I've just looked at the postgres console, there's no broken records, with the association (activity_id = 4) but no data.

Behind the scenes:

/models/activity.rb

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
end
```

/models/review.rb

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :activity
end
```

Comment: It is not nil, it is an empty model. It did not get there by itself, someone placed it there. Could you show the whole action + model?

Answer (score 1):

The `CollectionProxy` object *is not* `nil`, as you've stated. `@activity` actually has *one* `Review` – the problem is that the `Review` has an `id` of `nil`. Not sure how this happened, but you can rectify this from the Rails console:

```
# from command line, enter `rails console` to enter the console
Review.find(nil).destroy
```

Comment: Wish that were the case: `>> Review.find(nil)`
`!! #<ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Review without an ID>`

Comment: In case there was _anything_ funny in the DB, I just declared Data-Bankruptcy, with `rake db:reset`, and... I still have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The point at which the @activity.reviews was being executed, was on a show page, after a form_for. It looks like form_for makes a new activity.review. It doesn't get saved/created, just at the time. So, it just creates junk, which gives me the CollectionProxy that is basically nil, but has the activity_id for the current activity.

```
<h2>Add a review</h2>
<%= form_for([@activity, @activity.reviews.build]) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :rating %><br>
        <%= f.number_field :rating %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :reviewer_name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :reviewer_name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :description %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :description %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>


<h2>Reviews</h2>
<% @reviews.each do |review| %>
    <p><%= "#{review.reviewer_name} - #{review.rating} - #{review.description}"%></p>
<% end %>
```

Cheers to zeantsoi and BroiSatse, for helping me on the right path to solve this.

My choices are to either move the Reviews BEFORE the Add-A-Review, or to add some further nil-checking.

Comment: This makes sense, being that the error was in the view. Since you had cited snippets from the Rails console, I had assumed that the error was in the console/controller. Mentioning the location/nature of the error might elicit more concise errors in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on clearer questions. This was output from my view, using the gems better_errors and binding_of_caller, you get a console in your view error. My poor mans debugging involves something like `@reviews.to_explosion` to give me a console at the specific breakpoint.